# Is it good idea to transfer huge data (probably in MB's) from Server to Client with JSON?

Tags: json

Actually I was facing "out of memeory" problem because of huge data processing on server side but now I have solved this problem using CallbackRowHandler to process data in chunks. That works fine. Now I am facing again same "out of memory" problem because of transfering processed data towards Client side. I am thinking of using json to transfer processed data towards Client. Please tell me is it good approach or am I going on wrong direction? 
Thank you Jimon

Comment: I think it depends on what you are up to but you haven't mentioned  much about that, however , JSON is good for data transfers of web services ,that's why Google,twitter use JSON!

Comment: actually as server side response I have list of Map (maps contains string infos).... but when the list size goes around one million then Out of memory exception accurs; thats why i want to use JSON to transfer data ... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to transfer `huge data` from `server` to `client`. As it will require more `bandwidth` and puts a `load` to the `client`. It's recommended to send the data in `pagination`.

Comment: thanks for reply; but our project requirement is to process and make graphical representation of complete data at once :)

Comment: You mean to say that you need to send the data to the client side and there you analyze the data and make graphical representation to summarize the data, right?

Comment: its better to summarize the data on server side and send the summarized data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

In case your question is still valid you can try to assemble a JSON file and upload in a similar manner with a text or image file.

You will be able to to transfer several Megabytes, save the file in a folder and finally parse the json file.

It will be slower but will work.